# quick sort error in c++ using classes

Tags: c++, sorting

I did a program in C++ using classes and objects for quick sort .
I have compiled this on online compilers and found that it is timedout because this code takes too much time and memory.

When I later compiled it on Visual C++ 2010, it said `unhandled exception : stack overflow`
I trying to figure out the infinite loop running at the class member function `void quick sort (a[],l,r)`. Please help out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sort;

int main()
{
    class sort
    {
    public:
        int split(int a[],int l,int r)
        {
            int i,j,p,t;
            p=a[l];
            i=(l+1);
            j=r;

            while (l<=r)
            {
                while ((a[i]<p)&&(i<j))
                    r--;

                while ((a[j]>p)&&(l<r))
                    l++;

                if (i<=j)
                {
                    t=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=t;
                }
            }
            t=p;
            p=a[j];
            a[j]=p;

            return j;
        }


        void quicksort(int a[],int l,int r)
        {
            int s;
            if (l<r)
            {
                s=split(a,l,r);
                quicksort(a,l,(s-1));
                quicksort(a,(s+1),l);
            }
        }

    } obj1;

    int a[30],n,i;

    cout<<"\nEnter no of elements :\t 5";
    n=5;

    cout<<"\nEnter elements :\n";
    a[0]=9;
    a[1]=6;
    a[2]=3;
    a[3]=5;
    a[4]=1;

    cout<<"\nElemets before sort :\n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<" "<<a[i];

    obj1.quicksort(a,0,(n-1));

    cout<<"\nElements after sort:\n";
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<" "<<a[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it in the VC debugger and it will point you at where the exception is thrown. That should get you started in finding the error.

Comment: Run it in a debugger, investigate the stack trace once the stack overflow happens

Comment: and please indent your code properly. I was scanning it to see if something jumped out at me, but I got tired of trying to just match braces. If you can't be bothered to write legibly I'm not going to be bothered trying to help you.

Comment: Quicksort does *not* need to be this complicated. As a general rule, if you're code ever infinite-loops (and since you're only sorting 5 elements and it times out, that is exactly what it is happening) it is almost a guarantee that either your partition algorithm is broken, or your forgetting to *exclude* the pivot element when sorting subsequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

```
int split(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    int i,j,p,t;
    p=a[l];
    i=(l+1);
    j=r;

    // consider what will happen for an array with just 1 or 2 elements?
    while (l<=r) // should be while i<=j;
    {
        while ((a[i]<p)&&(i<j))
            r--; //should be j--

        while ((a[j]>p)&&(l<r))
            l++; // should be i++

        if (i<=j) // sadly this will only true when you've got an array with 1 element 
        {
            t=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=t;
        }
    }
    t=p;
    p=a[j];
    a[j]=p;

    return j;
}
```

The key issue is that quicksort algorithm is incorrect here. it works as follows:

```
0. make i = l+1 and j = r;

1. while true:

1.1 while a[i]<a[l] i++

1.2 while a[j]>a[l]  j--

1.3 break if i>= j;

1.4 exchange a[i] and a[j]

2. exchange a[l] and a[j]
```

You are doing different things in your implementation.